# How to move folder

Tags: command-line

Can you tell me how to move a folder? I am trying to use `mv` but it does not work! I use Ubuntu and I am new.

Comment: normaly you would do: `mv path/to/folder path/to/moved_folder` - best would be if you post what u did write in termianl including the output, so we see what you problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

The command is `mv foldername newfoldername`

Example (`mv` `/tmp/huy` to be `/tmp/huyN`):

```
cd /tmp
/tmp$ mkdir huy
/tmp$ touch huy/testfile
/tmp$ mv huy huyN
/tmp$ ll huyN/
total 24
drwxrwxr-x  2 user  user    4096 Feb 21 09:48 ./
drwxrwxrwt 36 root root 20480 Feb 21 09:48 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 user   user       0 Feb 21 09:48 testfile
/tmp$
```

More info: [man mv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mv.1.html)